# Find-in-files keyboard shortcut to switch between files and Edit box

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

In Intellij idea, in Find-in-files is there a keyboard shortcut to switch between files and Edit box.  1 and 2 in screenshot?

[image]

Comment: No shortcut at the moment. Please upvote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-230848

Comment: Done @EgorKlepikov Thanks for your fast response!!!